# Linux thread observation: Determine entry point of thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, proc

to check my system for performance issues, I would like to detect thread creations.
This can be easily done, by checking the procfs, for newly created "task" folders.

However, beside of the information THAT a thread was created, I'd also like to know which thread it was: Meaning, I want to get the start address of the function that runs in its own thread (The function name I can obtain from debug symbols...).

So far, I couldn't find any information on this in procfs. Only the stack pointers for different threads are given, but I don't think that I can determine the "thread function" based on this information.

Therefore my questions are:

1. Does someone have an idea how to determine thread entries by the information given in procfs?
2. Does someone know a better way to get the information?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards
Jean-Pierre

Comment: Would it not be easier to just put log entries in the code and rebuild?  The start address does not identify a thread anyway, in general.

Comment: Unfortunaelty I need the more generic approach for my project and also monitor 3rd party applications :(.

Comment: About your second comment, I'm not sure. With the name of the main process, the functions address and the debug symbols, I should have enough information to identify the thread. Or is there something I did not consider?

Comment: multiple threads running the same function code.

Comment: Yes. Good point :D. In the meantime I checked some other possibilities, but I'm afraid that lttng and systemtap are too large for my simple purpose. Currently, I also wonder whether ptrace is an option...